# How to fill a particular section of a UICollectionView a different color than the rest?

Tags: colors, cell, background-color, uicollectionview

I have a single row collectionview with a number of cells. How would I fill a particular section of the UICollectionView with a different color than the rest? For instance, if I wanted the right of the last cell to the end of the row to be a different background color than what the background color is underneath the cells.